# Why does my lookup vector cast NAs for some values?

Tags: r, lookup

I tried to assign values to a key using a lookupt-vector but somehow, the look-up vetor doesn't seem "cope" with all my values the same way.

First of all I want to show you my lookup-table with "X.box_nr" as my values and "durchmesser2019" as my key, which I createt as a subset of a bigger data set:

```
> Durchmesser2019 <- subset(ohneNA, jahr == 2019, select = c(X.box_nr, durchmesser2019))
> Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019 <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019)
> Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr)
> Durchmesser2019

     X.box_nr durchmesser2019
42          6              26
56          7              26
65          9              26
106        14              26
119        15              32
121        16              26
171        22              26
230        29              26
234        30              32
270        34              32
273        35              26
290        37              32
301        38              32
329        42              26
366        46              26
370        47              26
386        49              26
422        53              26
442        56              32
466        59              32
479        60              32
530        67              26
577        73              26
589        74              26
596        75              26
607        76              26
659        83              26
887       111              26
958       120              32
980       123              26
989       124              26
1027      129              26
1069      134              26
1292      162              26
1324      166              26
1363      171              32
1429      179              26
1463      183              26
1473      185              32
1515      190              32
1534      192              26
1550      194              32
1564      196              26
1597      200              32
1631      204              32
1676      210              32
1684      211              26
1692      212              32
1747      219              26
1956      245              26
2029      254              26
2068      259              26
2160      270              26
2333      292              26
```

> 

Then I proceeded with the following code:

```
Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019 <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019)
Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr)

getdurchmesser2019 <- Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019

names(getdurchmesser2019) <- Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr

unname(getdurchmesser2019[])
```

Here, I found, that I do get the right key, if I insert the number 53 into the square bracket of the last code, but I get an "NA" if I insert the number 74 instead.

Do you happen to have any idea why this might be?

I found out, that I do get the write key for N.box_nr 74 if I set the numbers into invertet commas.

But actually I would like to know, why the values can't be proceeded in the same manner by the lookup-vector in order to be able to automize the look-up-process using this function:

```
getdurchmesser_2019 <- function(X.box_nr, lookupvector = getdurchmesser2019){
  durchmesser2019 <- unname(lookupvector[X.box_nr])
  return(durchmesser2019)
}
```

I already tried to set the columns of the look-up table as numeric (see the code abough).

Comment: `getdurchmesser2019[74]` doesn't get you the value in the slot named "74", it gets you the value in the 74th slot.  How long is the vector?

Comment: Oh, that's good to know! Do you happen to know how I might receive the key of the value in the slot named "74" using a function?

Comment: I've added an answer with a few options including a function version.

Comment: To get the value in the slot named `74` try: `getdurchmesser2019["74"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer given by @TarJae if you provide a number for indexing it will be used for a positional match, not a name match.  I have used their example data frame as well.

Options:

```
Durchmesser2019[Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr == 53,]
```

This compares each value of `Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr` with the value `53` and returns a vector of true or false as to whether or not they match.  This vector is then used to subset the rows of your data frame.

the output is a data frame:
(note, it may have more than one row if more than one match is found)

```
> Durchmesser2019[Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr == 53,]
    X.box_nr durchmesser2019
422       53              26
```

Alternatively, we can subset the `$durchmesser2019` column using the same indexing:

```
Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019[Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr == 53]
```

Which will return a scalar instead, if there is only one match.

```
> Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019[Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr == 53]
[1] 26

> Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019[Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr == 53] |> str()
 num 26
```

As requested, with a function:

```
getDurch <- function(lookup, df){
  return(df$durchmesser2019[df$X.box_nr == lookup])
}

> getDurch(53, Durchmesser2019)
[1] 26
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector `getdurchmesser2019` has length 54.
Everything after 54 will be `NA`.

data:

```
Durchmesser2019 <- structure(list(X.box_nr = c(6, 7, 9, 14, 15, 16, 22, 29, 30, 
34, 35, 37, 38, 42, 46, 47, 49, 53, 56, 59, 60, 67, 73, 74, 75, 
76, 83, 111, 120, 123, 124, 129, 134, 162, 166, 171, 179, 183, 
185, 190, 192, 194, 196, 200, 204, 210, 211, 212, 219, 245, 254, 
259, 270, 292), durchmesser2019 = c(26, 26, 26, 26, 32, 26, 26, 
26, 32, 32, 26, 32, 32, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 32, 32, 32, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 32, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 32, 26, 26, 32, 
32, 26, 32, 26, 32, 32, 32, 26, 32, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26)), row.names = c("42", 
"56", "65", "106", "119", "121", "171", "230", "234", "270", 
"273", "290", "301", "329", "366", "370", "386", "422", "442", 
"466", "479", "530", "577", "589", "596", "607", "659", "887", 
"958", "980", "989", "1027", "1069", "1292", "1324", "1363", 
"1429", "1463", "1473", "1515", "1534", "1550", "1564", "1597", 
"1631", "1676", "1684", "1692", "1747", "1956", "2029", "2068", 
"2160", "2333"), class = "data.frame")
```

```
Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019 <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019)
Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr <- as.numeric(Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr)
getdurchmesser2019 <- Durchmesser2019$durchmesser2019
names(getdurchmesser2019) <- Durchmesser2019$X.box_nr


dim(Durchmesser2019)

[1] 54  2

length(getdurchmesser2019)
[1] 54
```

If you do:

```
unname(getdurchmesser2019[54])
[1] 26

unname(getdurchmesser2019[55])
[1] NA
```